# How to convert an Int32 array pointer to an Int8_t array pointer?

Tags: c++11

Any idea.
I tried this:

```
int *p = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
...//set the value of p
int8_t *q = reinterpret_cast<int8_t *>(p);
```

But it doesn't work. I want to get the result q to be 
continuous. But the result shows that, if p has 4 elements:{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, Then q would be {1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0}

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get build errors? Crashes when running? Unexpected output? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us. Please *edit your question* to include more details and more (relevant) code.

Comment: You can try that using some initial values. The result int8_t array is not 
continuous like p[0], 0, 0, 0, p[1], 0, 0, 0....

Comment: Your code will compile fine. What doesn't work? I believe you have wrong expectations as to what is supposed to happen. Can you specify example input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't act as you expect because `reinterpret_cast` won't change those `int`s into `int8_t`s, it'll just reinterpret the value representation of the `int`s as bytes. Instead of using `malloc` and `reinterpret_cast` you should use `std::vector`:

```
//create an int vector of size N
std::vector<int> p (N); 

//copy p contents into a vector of int8_t
std::vector<int8_t> q {p.begin(), p.end()};
```

Then if you *really* need a `int8_t` you can use `q.data()`, but it's far preferable to just use the vector or iterators to it instead of raw pointers.

Comment: You might want to point out that when creating the `int8_t` vector, values outside the range of `int8_t` will be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

You cast a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type. You're basically only assign a pointer to another pointer. That's it.

There is no copying of the data the first pointer is pointing to. There is no modification of the data the first pointer is pointing to. After the assignment you will have two different pointers both pointing to the exact same data.

Something like this:

```
+---+
| p | --\
+---+    \     +------------------------------+
          >--> | 32-bit integer data here ... |
+---+    /     +------------------------------+
| q | --/
+---+
```

---

As for why the 32-bit integer `1` is resulting in the four bytes `1`, `0`, `0` and `0`, first remember that `1` as a 32-bit integer is equal to `0x00000001`, i.e. three bytes of zeroes and a byte with the value `1`. That the zeroes and one seems reversed is because of you being on a [*little-endian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little) system.

Comment: In my case, the 32bit integers range in [-127,128], which means that those integer can be int8. Is there any function can fit the long bytes into the lower?